# Delay rendering of body until a Javascript variable is available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a standard html page in which I am using Javascript and jQuery to load user data from an API that returns data in JSON. Part of this user data us a language identifier. Then I have various language files, they are e.g. en.js, nl.js, sl.js and contain an array where the key is a tag and the value is a translated text string. E.g.

```
language = [];
language["salutation"] = "Hello";
```

I have localisation function

```
GetLangStringWrite = function (token, defaultValue) {
    try {
        if (typeof language[token] == "undefined") {
            document.write(defaultValue);
        } else {
            document.write(language[token]);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        document.write(defaultValue);
    }
}
```

This function is called within the body tag, e.g.

```
<div>
    <script>GetLangStringWrite('salutation', 'Hi');</script>
</div>
```

When I load the language file e.g. en.js directly in the header of my html file all works fine.

I am loading the language file using the following method:

```
<script>
var loadLanguageTimer;

function LoadLanguage() {
    if ((typeof ENV !== "undefined") && (typeof ENV.ud.language !== "undefined")) {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "javascript/" + ENV.ud.language + ".js";
        $("head").append(s);
        clearTimeout(loadLanguageTimer);
        return;
    }
    loadLanguageTimer = setTimeout(LoadLanguage, 250);
}

LoadLanguage();
</script>
```

When I make a mechanism that checks if the language parameter is available from the JSON file and then load either en.js, nl.js, etv. things get "messy".

The loading mechanism works fine but the html body and the *GetLangStringWrite('salutation', 'Hi');* code is already executed/rendered before the language file could be loaded. Hence the API takes time to get the data.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, e.g. delay rendering of the body until JSON api is available or even something better. A better approach might have been not to include the  but use an *id* and use jQuery to set the value, unfortunately time does not permit that to fix it for the demo I have in 12 hours.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This is yet another reason to *not* use `document.write`. If you're using `document.write`, you can't delay the output whatsoever. You would definitely need to restructure this slightly to make this even remotely possible.

Comment: What approach would you use @JakeKing?

Comment: How are you loading the loading the language files in JavaScript? Can you provide a code example please?

Comment: @SeanDunwoody, I've added the code snippet you requested.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll have a look for you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write`: it's synchronous, and you immediately see its shortcomings as soon as you want to do something asynchronous. Here's a better solution.

Instead of using inline script tags that call functions to use `document.write`, create divs with data attributes that will be filled in later.

```
<div data-localization-token="salutation">Hi</div>
```

Then, when you receive the JSON data with the language identifier, perform the following in the callback:

```
$("[data-localization-token]").each(function () {
    var token = $(this).data('localizationToken');
    if (typeof language[token] != 'undefined') {
        $(this).html(language[token]);
    }
});
```

You may need to do some additional loading to populate `language` based on the JSON, but from your question, it would seem you've already handled that yourself.

Comment: Do you think I can use the GetLangStringWrite function to make the <div data-localization-token="salutation">Hi</div> and then use your for each function to assign the values? There are a lot of functions in the various html pages that have document.write and I don't know if I have time to fix them all tonight. Would it work you think?

Comment: @MarcWitteveen Yes, that should work fine, though I'd recommend you replace them eventually, obviously.

Comment: It seems your idea will solve the part within the html body. TNX. Next problem is that I have a few JS files that render some html, a few work because they are waiting on user data but e.g. the JS that renders the menu dynamically shows the wrong text. The function is similar to the top one but have a return instead of document.write. Any idea?